# Python Selenium opens Website but then Website closes

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I wanna write a programm that opens a website for me and doesnt closes it right after

I tried to open a website and expected it to stay open but it didnt

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

service_object_name = Service(r'C:\SneakerPython\chromedriver.exe')
options_name = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options_name.add_argument("--start-maximized")
browser = webdriver.Chrome(service=service_object_name, options=options_name)
browser.get("https://www.solebox.com/de_DE/p/jordan-air_jordan_1_retro_high_og_%22gorge_green%22-gorge_green%2Fmetallic_silver-wht-02142227.html")
```

Comment: The code looks fine. what do you mean by 'to stay open'. Do you want the webpage always open?

Answer (score 0):

You can add the option ***detach*** to let your browser open after your code has been executed :

> detach (Boolean) — whether browser is closed when the driver is sent the quit command

I have also modified your code adding ChromeDriverManager that allows to dynamically install the correct chromedriver for your machine.

Just run the following command in your terminal:

> pip install webdriver-manager

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager


options_name = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options_name.add_argument("--start-maximized")
options_name.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
browser = webdriver.Chrome(
            service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=options_name
        )
browser.get("https://www.solebox.com/de_DE/p/jordan-air_jordan_1_retro_high_og_%22gorge_green%22-gorge_green%2Fmetallic_silver-wht-02142227.html")
```